# Sending dynamic data to XML file from a HTML page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xml

**Please help me on sending specific data only 'Name' and 'ON' or 'OFF' to XML file from a HTML page.
Problem is I couldn't connect all these with each other to get a result like below**

```
<name>RYAN</name>
<BREAKING>ON</BREAKING>
```

*Here is my code below:*

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>BREAKING NEWS SWITCH</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:500px;">
   <h2 align="center">BREAKING NEWS SWITCH</h2><br /><br />
   <form method="post" id="insert_data">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>Enter Your Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name Please....?"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>BREAKING NEWS</label>
     <div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="BREAKING" id="BREAKING" unchecked />
     </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_BREAKING" id="hidden_BREAKING" value="OFF" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="insert" id="action" class="btn btn-info" value="Insert" />
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('#BREAKING').bootstrapToggle({
  on: 'ON',
  off: 'OFF',
  onstyle: 'success',
  offstyle: 'danger'
 });

 $('#BREAKING').change(function(){
  if($(this).prop('unchecked'))
  {
   $('#hidden_BREAKING').val('OFF');
  }
  else
  {
   $('#hidden_BREAKING').val('ON');
  }
 });

 $('#insert_data').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  if($('#name').val() == '')
  {
   alert("Please Enter Your Name");
   return false;
  }
  else
  {
   var form_data = $(this).serialize();
   $.ajax({
    url:"file:///C:/Documents/MY%20Projects/PHP%20toggles/BREAKING%20NEWS/insert.PHP",
    method:"POST",
    data:form_data,
    success:function(data){
     if(data == 'done')
     {
      $('#insert_data')[0].reset();
      $('#BREAKING').bootstrapToggle('off');
      alert("Data Inserted");
     }
    }
   });
  }
 });

});
</script>
```

**Here the problem is I can't connect those with the PHP file below.**

**PHP:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['insert']))
{
    $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
    $xml->load("C:\Documents\MY Projects\PHP toggles\BREAKING NEWS\TEMPLATE.xml");

    $rootTag = $xml->getElementsByTagName("XML")->item(0);

    $nameTag = $xml->createElement("name",$_REQUEST['name']);
    $BREAKINGTag = $xml->createElement("BREAKING",$_REQUEST['BREAKING']);

    $xml->save("C:\Documents\MY Projects\PHP toggles\BREAKING NEWS\TEMPLATE.xml");

}

?>
```

**And thus this xml file is not updating as expected.**

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XML>
    <name>NAMES INSERTED SHOULD BE HERE</name>
    <BREAKING>TOGGLE ON/OFF SHOULD BE HERE</BREAKING>
</XML>
```

***Please help me on that.***

Comment: When you say "can't connect", does that mean you get a failure during a HTTP request? You were very un-specific about the error. I mention this because I can see that `url:"C:\Documents\MY Projects\PHP toggles\BREAKING NEWS\insert.PHP` is wrong. A path on disk is not the same as a URL. It should be something like either just `insert.php` (to get a link relative to the current URL that the HTML page is being served from), or a full URL something like `http://localhost/someappname/insert.php`. Please make sure you understand what a URL is, and is not.

Comment: Also, if you use your browser's Developer Tools and check the Console and Network areas within that, you'll be able to see error messages and debug your Javascript/AJAX code much more easily.

Comment: P.S. Your insert.php file doesn't need its own HTML form if you're actually calling it via AJAX from a different form...just the PHP will be sufficient.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your input. I didn't get what did you mean by **Own HTML form?**

Comment: @ADyson did you mean I don't need insert.PHP file?

Comment: @ADyson my localhost is not working. says CORS Policy issue.

Comment: `what did you mean by Own HTML form?` ... I mean that in the insert.php file you've shown a HTML form. But you don't appear to be using that form to submit the data, you seem to be using the form from another file instead. So it's likely you don't need the form in insert.php, you only need to keep the PHP code in that file - it will respond to the AJAX request from the other file and return a response, without needing to display any HTML by itself.

Comment: `my localhost is not working. says CORS Policy issue`...what is the _exact_ error message please? And...are you serving your HTML file over `http://` or over `file://`? You always need to use `http://`, otherwise AJAX requests won't work properly (and neither will PHP).

Comment: @ADyson thanks. I am able to set up localhost, but still it says **POST http://localhost/insert.PHP 404 (Not Found)                   jquery.min.js:4**

Comment: Well 404 not found means the URL is wrong. So presumably insert.php is not in the root folder of the site you created

Comment: @ADyson thanks mate. I got it. but still it says 
**POST http://localhost/insert.PHP 405 (Method Not Allowed)               jquery.min.js:4**

Comment: That will be an issue with your server config not allowing POST requests to that URL. I don't know what webserver you used, but I'm sure you can probably find information about it online, and how to enable the different HTTP methods such as GET, POST etc.